# Dimension of Dataset Many to Many one to Many in LSTM keras

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, keras

My understanding is In Many to Many dimension of if X is`(batch_size,timestep,vector_size)` and Y is `(batch_size,timestep,vector_size)`. And in case of Many to one X is `(batch_size,timestep,vector_size)` and
Y is  `(batch_size,1,vector_size)`.
But what confuses me is keras accepts dimenson like this `X=(5,3,1)` and `Y=(5,4,1)`. Where timestep in Y is greater than in X. It also accepts less than in X. I am not able to interpret it.